# Customers, Suppliers and their Employees

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm designing a marketplace where customer can order products from suppliers. I need help in defining the database scheme.

I have two types of companies: Customers and Suppliers. Suppliers can have their own Customers (and one Customer can belong to many Suppliers). Both Customers and Suppliers can have their own employees: Managers and Assistants that can login to the application and access tables based on their user role, and can access only the records of the company they belong to.

When registering to the application user must choose user type (Customer or Supplier) in the registration form, then after registration, he/she gets the role "Manager" automatically. After that, as a manager they can add company info and employees. Only Managers can add company info and employees to the system.

Customers and Suppliers can have different company attributes that's why I separated them into two tables.

1. I created the below schema for this scenario but not sure this is the right way. What would be a better solution?
2. This scenario generates another problem: when managers register, they are added to the Employee table, but at this time they don't belong to any company yet since they haven't added their company info thus don't have a customer_id or supplier_id in the employee table. Only when they add their company info they get the customer or supplier id (company id) of the new company. However, in order to associate them with their company, this company id needs to be added back to the manager's record in the employee table. I think this is not how it should be done but can't come up with a better solution.
   I'm trying to resolve this problem with an "employee_id" in both Customers and Suppliers table. This way, when managers add company info, their "employee_id" will be saved in Customers or Suppliers table together with company info. This way manager will be associated one-to-one with a company. That is a manager can access only one company, the one he owns. Later when managers add employees to the company, it gets easier because the company already exists so the supplier or customer id will be saved with employee record.

How to do this the right way?

TABLES:

Employees:

- id
- customer_id NULL (FK of Customers)
- supplier_id NULL (FK of Suppliers)
- fname
- lname
- email
- password
- user_type (Customer or Supplier)
- role (Manager or Assistant)

Customers:

- id
- employee_id (FK of Employees)
- company_name
- contact_name

Suppliers:

- id
- employee_id (FK of Employees)
- company_name
- contact_name

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it like this, you will regret it. Use the Party Model and Table Inheritance.

There are Relationships between Parties, such as Frank is an Organization Contact of Acme Inc. Or Jim is an Employee of BizCo.

You can also use Declared Roles, for someone you might not have a relationship with, such as a Lead or Supplier you haven't done business with yet.

This schema is advantageous for the following reasons:

- You can sell (via a sales order) to an individual or organization (with one foreign key)
- A party can play multiple roles / have multiple relationships at the same time
- No duplication

Using Single Table Inheritance here, but you can use Class Table Inheritance if you don't like nulls. Using PostgreSQL style SQL here, but easy to adjust for MySQL.

```
create table party_type (
  id int primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into party_type values
(1, 'Individual'),
(2, 'Organization');


create table party (
  id serial primary key,
  type int not null references party_type(id),
  organization_name text null,
  first_name text null,
  last_name text null
);



create table party_relationship_type (
  id int primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into party_relationship_type values 
(1, 'Organization Contact'),
(2, 'Employment');


create table party_relationship (
  from_party_id int not null references party(id),
  to_party_id int not null references party(id),
  type int not null references party_relationship_type(id),
  primary key (from_party_id, to_party_id, type),
  check (from_party_id <> to_party_id)
);

/* note: no check constraints in mysql, you will have to use a trigger, or use Postgres. Don't need roles, but can be handy */

create table party_role_type (
  id int primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into party_role_type values 
(1, 'Customer'),
(2, 'Supplier');


create table party_role (
  party_id int not null references party(id),
  party_role_type_id int not null references party_role_type(id),
  primary key (party_id, party_role_type)
);
```

Comment: Agreed, however check constraint won't work on MySQL, he's gonna have to use triggers.

Comment: Thank you. It looks very efficient. I assume in this case party.type will contain Customer or Supplier, and party_role.party_role_type_id will contain Manager or Assistant. Then what is the field party_relationship.type for?

Comment: 2. I forgot to say that an employee can belong to only one company, and can have only one role. Actually it is a user group not role. Considering this, how would you change your scheme? I will use Eloquent ORM so my possibilities are somewhat limited. 3. Would a polymorphic relation suit for this case? I mean using my original solution, except we use one FK let's say "company_id" instead of the supplier_id and customer_id in Employee table. Then company_id together with user_type will define which subtype and which row of the subtype we link to.

Comment: 4. And since an employee can belong only to one company, the employee-company relation is a many-to-one. That's why I thougt we could keep the relation only in the user table with the help of the company_id FK. Does that make sense?

Comment: 1. Party Type is Individual or Organization (use inheritance for things that can never change).  Party Role is Supplier or Customer. Manager or Assistant can be a Party Relationship.

Comment: 2. These are business rules and not data model rules. You should enforce them in the application layer. What if you decide later that someone can work for more than one company? What if you sell to and buy from the same company?